# Member function of class not retaining value after constructing

Tags: javascript, function, class, coffeescript

I have a class for a button, and I would like to be able to pass a function to it on creation. The code for the class is here:

```
class Button extends PIXI.Sprite
    constructor: (image, @f) -> 
        super()
        console.log("Button built!");
        @.texture = PIXI.Texture.fromImage(image);


    isClicked = false;

    setClicked: -> 
        isClicked = true; 
        console.log(isClicked);

    doThing: ->
        if isClicked
            isClicked = false;
            f();
        else
            isClicked = false;
```

The constructing code is:

```
for = function(){
    console.log("foo");
}

bar = new Button('bar.png', foo);
```

f() exists during the constructor, but when doThing() is called later, f() is empty. I don't think it's a scope thing, as I've tried directly applying foo() outside of the constructor and it doesn't work. Alternatively, is there a better pattern for what I want to be doing? (which is be able to create buttons that are attached to functions that fire code off to the server via websocket, but that's later)

Answer (score 0):

The secret was to include @/this in my function call of f(). I don't know why. Can someone explain please?

```
doThing: ->
    if isClicked
        isClicked = false;
        @f();
    else
        isClicked = false;
```

Comment: `f()` is a plain function call but there is no `f` in scope. `@f()` OTOH is a *method* call on `@`, it is the same as saying `this.f()` and not the `@f` instance variable assignment in the `constructor`'s argument list. You'd probably also want to say `@isClicked` (so that `isClicked` is an instance variable) and replace `isClicked = false;` in the class with `@isClicked = false` in `constructor`.